# Configuring MVC app using Auth0 for ClaimsIdentity and nameidentifier error msgs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity, auth0

I'm using the [Auth0-Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Auth0-MVC/) NuGet package (latest 0.9.1) with MVC 4 in VS 2015.
Targeting .NET 4.5.2

When specifying a `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in a partial view, I encounter a

> A  claim of type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier' or 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider' was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity. To enable anti-forgery token support with claims-based authentication, please verify that the configured claims provider is providing both of these claims on the ClaimsIdentity instances it generates. If the configured claims provider instead uses a different claim type as a unique identifier, it can be configured by setting the static property AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier.

Using other [advice for similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977833/anti-forgery-token-issue-mvc-5), I modify `Global.asax.cs` to include:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
}
```

This leads to:

> A  claim of type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier' was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity.

**How can I modify my code to solve this ClaimsIdentity and nameidentifier issue?**

I've checked the MVC 4 sample encounters an unresolvable runtime error, and its source doesn't have any modifications found out in the community. It does have `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, so I'm hoping there's a solution.

My `CallbackHandler.ashx` is same as delivered in the NuGet package 0.9.1

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var token = client.ExchangeAuthorizationCodePerAccessToken(context.Request.QueryString["code"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:CallbackUrl"]);
        var profile = client.GetUserInfo(token.AccessToken);

        var user = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "name", profile.Name??"" },
            { "email", profile.Email??"" },
            { "family_name", profile.FamilyName??"" },
            { "given_name", profile.GivenName??"" },
            { "gender", profile.Gender??"" },
            { "nickname", profile.Nickname??"" },
            { "picture", profile.Picture??"" },
            { "user_id", profile.UserId??"" },
            { "id_token", token.IdToken }
        };

        ClaimsCookie.ClaimsCookieModule.Instance.CreateSessionSecurityToken(user);

        var claimedUser = new User
        {
            AccessToken = user["id_token"],
            UserID = user["user_id"],
            Name = user["name"],
            Email = user["email"],
            NickName = user["nickname"],
            ProfilePicUrl = user["picture"]
        };

        //go save to database.
        //then redirect to another URL
```