# MVC 5 OWIN login with claims and AntiforgeryToken. Do I miss a ClaimsIdentity provider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to learn Claims for MVC 5 OWIN login. I try'ed to keep it as simple as possible. I started with the MVC template and inserted my claims code (see below). I get an error when I use the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() helper in the View.

**Error:**

```
A claim of type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier' or  
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovid    
er' was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity. 

To enable anti-forgery token support with claims-based authentication, please verify that 
the configured claims provider is providing both of these claims on the ClaimsIdentity 
instances it generates. If the configured claims provider instead uses a different claim 
type as a unique identifier, it can be configured by setting the static property 
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A claim of type
'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier' or 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider' was 
not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity. To enable anti-forgery token
support with claims-based authentication, please verify that the configured claims provider 
is providing both of these claims on the ClaimsIdentity instances it generates. 
If the configured claims provider instead uses a different claim type as a unique 
identifier, it can be configured by setting the static property 
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier.

Source Error:
Line 4:      using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new 
{ id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
Line 5:      {
Line 6:      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

**POST Login action**

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Brock"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "brockallen@gmail.com")
    };
    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
    var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
    authenticationManager.SignIn(id);

    return RedirectToAction("Welcome");
}
```

**_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
    }
}
```

I have tryed setting `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` ([like in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977833/anti-forgery-token-issue-mvc-5))

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
}
```

And then I "only?" get this error

```
A claim of type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier' was 
not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity.
```

I want to keep the antiforgeryToken because it can help against cross-site scripting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your claim identity does not have `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`, you should add more into claim array:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "username"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "user@gmail.com"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "userId"), //should be userid
};
```

To map the information to Claim for more corrective:

```
ClaimTypes.Name => map to username
ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier => map to user_id
```

Since username is unique also, so you are able to use `username` for anti-forgery token support.

Comment: I don't know what the mapping does. First I inserted the `NameIdentifier` too but got the same error. Then I tryed adding in Global.asax.cs without knowing what it does, but now it works. Maybe it's the same as your mapping?

Global.asax.cs.:
 AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Name;
            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Email;
            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;

Comment: The error message in the question mentions `identityprovider` which doesn't exist as a constant in `ClaimTypes` in ASP.NET MVC 4.6.1. Therefore it appears as if @travis-russi seems to fit better. In this answer `new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "userId')` would suffice since `AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier` is set to  `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`.

Answer (score 18):

In your `Application_Start()`, specify which `Claim` to use as the `NameIdentifier`:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = 
            System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;

        ...
    }
}
```

See: http://brockallen.com/2012/07/08/mvc-4-antiforgerytoken-and-claims/

Comment: Thanks Travis, this fixed my issue right away.... Experienced it when applying Auto 0 to OWIN Asp.net

Answer (score 5):

**AntiForgeryConfig**

One way to solve it is to set AntiForgeryConfig to use other ClaimType.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Email;
}
```

**Add NameIdentifier and IdentityProvider ClaimTypes**

Alternatively, you can add NameIdentifier and IdentityProvider ClaimTypes to your claims.

```
List<Claim> _claims = new List<Claim>();
_claims.AddRange(new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", _user.Email)),
    new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", _user.Email)
})
```

See: https://stack247.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/antiforgerytoken-a-claim-of-type-nameidentifier-or-identityprovider-was-not-present-on-provided-claimsidentity/

Answer (score 3):

I used this on Global.asax.cs Application_Start() and solved the error:

AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Name;

Answer (score 2):

Your Global.asax.cs file should be like this:

```
namespace YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
         protected void Application_Start()
         {
             AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
             RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
             AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
         }
    }
}
```

Means If its not like thta, You have to add this code to that:

```
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
```

and Don't forget yo change "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME" with yours.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue to this that turned out to be cookie related; I was developing two MVC sites simultaneously and because ASP.Net sites all use the same cookie name by default the two sites were interfering with each other.  Clearing the cookies fixed the issue.  There's more on this in my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45980289/1879019).

Answer (score 0):

Use below in Global.cs

```
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType;
```

or you can also set your claim type as below in Global.cs

```
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
```

then add claims to claims list according to the claim type. Here is an example for claim type "name" and "nameidentifier. Use Session.SessionId or User.Identity.Name as name or nameidentifier.

```
 claims.Add(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", Session.SessionID));
 claims.Add(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Session.SessionID));
```